# Horizontal background image scrolling with directional controls on hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

Creating a horizontal continuous scrolling banner with a panoramic background image in a full width `div` having a default direction of moving from right to left.

**CSS**

```
.banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/800/');
    background-position: top left, center center;
    background-size: auto, cover;
 }

.moveControl {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.moveRight {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="moveControl">
    <div class="moveRight"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now when `:hover` on `div` with a class of `moveRight` it should move left to right direction from the same location where it was when `:hover`.

I did one directional scrolling using **jQuery**:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        "use strict";

        jQuery(window).load(function () {

            (function bgLoop() {
                $('.banner').animate({
                    'background-position': '-=50'
                }, 1000, 'linear', bgLoop);
            }());

        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

How can I stop the loop and start to moving the background image to the opposite direction when hovered from the same background position when it was hovered ? is this possible ?

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/odsbb9uw/5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are after but you could try something like this:

```js
function bgLoop(position) {
  $('.banner').stop().animate({
    'background-position': position
  }, 1000, 'linear', function() {
    bgLoop(position);
  });
}

$('.banner').hover(
  function() {
    bgLoop('+=50');
  },
  function() {
    bgLoop('-=50');
});

bgLoop('-=50');
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/odsbb9uw/7/)